# python 3.9 weird behaviour regarding input function

Tags: input, python-3.9

I am using python 3.9 in the newest Pycharm ide. I have a very simple 3 liner:

```
a=input()
b=input()
print(b)
```

I input 3, enter, then 4---but somehow the value 4 is not registered, and nothing is printed. Strangely enough, when I add a prompt to the second input function, everything returns normal

```
a=input()
b=input("test:")
print(b)
```

The output returns the value b as expected. I have looked everywhere online and could not explain this odd behaviour. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a pycharm setting. Had to enable "emulate terminal in output console" under run/edit configurations